# dynamic id creation for text field and getting the value of the text field?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I am constructing table with the checkbox in the servlet itself, and am trying to assigning a text field and id while selecting the checkbox, after assigning id am trying to get the value of check box selected textfield but i cant get the textfield value here i have included my code,

My servlet code is,

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        PreparedStatement distscenarioName = null;
        PreparedStatement minscenariId = null;
        PreparedStatement testcaseName = null;
        String scenari_name = null; 
        Connection connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        distscenarioName=connection.prepareStatement("select distinct scenario_name from scenario");
        ResultSet rs=distscenarioName.executeQuery();
        out.println("<tr><td><b>");
        out.println("Scenario Name:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase ID:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase Name:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase Description:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Action:");
        out.println("</b></td></tr>");
        while(rs.next()){
            scenari_name=rs.getString("scenario_name");
            minscenariId=connection.prepareStatement("select min(scenario_id) from scenario where scenario_name =?");
            minscenariId.setString(1, scenari_name);
            ResultSet rss=minscenariId.executeQuery();
            if(rss.next()){
                testcaseName=connection.prepareStatement("select tc_id,tc_desc,tc_name from testcase where scenario_id=?");
                testcaseName.setInt(1,rss.getInt("min(scenario_id)"));
                ResultSet testcaseExe=testcaseName.executeQuery();  
                out.println("<tr><td><h4>");
                out.println(scenari_name);
                out.println("</td></h4><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                while(testcaseExe.next()){

                    out.println("<tr><td>");
                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getInt(1));
                    out.println("</td>");
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_name"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_desc"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println("<input type=checkbox class='btnChckBox'>");
                    out.println("</td></tr>");
                }


            }
        }
```

and my jquery code is,

```
$.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "./ScenarioExecutionPage",
                        success : function(result) {
                            /* alert("Length"+result.toString().length); *//*
                                                                             * alert("length"+result.length());
                                                                             */
                            $("#testcaseTable").html(result);                               
                            $("#testcaseTable").show();
                            $("hide7").hide();
                            var par = $(this).parent().parent(); // tr
                            var btnChckBox = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
                            alert("alert "+btnChckBox);
                            btnChckBox.html("<input type='checkbox' class='btnChckBox'>");
                            $(".btnChckBox").bind("click",editM);
                            // $("#listC").html(result);
                        }
                    });


function editM(){
                    var i="";
                    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var tcDesc = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
                    var rowCount = $('#testcaseTable tr').length;
                    for(i=0; i<=rowCount; i++){
                        tcDesc.html("<input type='text' disabled='disabled' class='form-control'id='"+i+"' value='"+ tcDesc.html()+"'/>");
                        //var s = $("#tstcsDsc"+i+"").val();
                        alert("TC DESC-->"+$(""+i+"").val());

                    }
```

Comment: Thanks wolff, i tried its working i can get a text field value,thanks for a timing help.

Comment: if am selecting a one check box i can get the text field value and if am selecting a one more check box the previous value is overriding how can i get every text field value